# get value of data-initial-value using JS

Tags: javascript, html

hi i'm trying to get the text of this input filed but i'm getting this value **""**

```
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="xcx,n" badinput="false">
```

my code is :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput")[0].defaultValue
```

when i write something inside data-initial-value it show but how can i get that value?

Comment: did you try to change defaultValue by value ??

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `document.querySelector('.class1.class2')` to obtain just the first element with those two classes.
2. You can use `.dataset.initialValue` to get the value of the data-attribute.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput.exportInput')
  .dataset.initialValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="xcx,n" badinput="false">
```